# if statement for html/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about-us.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li> 
        <li><a href="contact-us.html">Contact</a></li>                        
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have the above code, which highlights Home button, since class is set to active.

What I want to do is, I want to put some sort of if condition, which detects which html files are loaded, and set class to active.

Probably something like `<li (if loaded.(about-us.html):class="active"><a href="about-us.html">About Us</a></li>` But this did not work.

Comment: It's a question. Did something confuse you? If so I'll edit.

Comment: Can you add the URL example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep this in some `js` file which you commonly load for all the pages and also add an `id` to your `ul`, say `nav` here. Assuming your `url` will be of format - **`www.somedomain.com/filename.html`**

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="nav">
```

**JS**

```
(function() {
    var nav = document.getElementById('nav'),
        anchor = nav.getElementsByTagName('a'),
        current = window.location.pathname.split('/')[1];
        for (var i = 0; i < anchor.length; i++) {
        if(anchor[i].href == current) {
            anchor[i].parentNode.className = "active";
        }
    }
})();
```

Also with `jquery` as below:

```
$(function() {
  $('#nav a[href^="/' + location.pathname.split("/")[1] + '"]')closest('li').addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is the jQuery .load event handler. It would probably be best to give the li an id, as well (for efficiency purposes):

```
<li id="home"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$( "#partBeingLoaded" ).load(function() {
   $("#home").addClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active" id="index"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li id="about-us"><a href="about-us.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li id="portfolio"><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li id="blog"><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li> 
        <li id="contact-us"><a href="contact-us.html">Contact</a></li>                        
    </ul>
</div>
```

set ids for each li tag

```
var href = document.location.href;
var filename = href.substr(href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
var temp = filename.split(".");
$("#"+temp[0]).addClass("active");
```

and on load of page you can use that page name as id to make it active